# Reading carriage return and new lines in Java

Tags: java, soap, tcp, stream

I have a SOAP XML that at the start has a custom header that I wrote. I have TCP/IP Connection, and I receive Header + SOAP XML. The header has at the end \r\n\r\n. When I try to read the socket, I use bufferInputstream and it has readnextline, and that removes that \r\n\r\n that I use which means that I reached the end of the header, and hence I can not decode the header correctly. Is there a function that can ignore the carriage return and new lines, and stores the socket response in a string ?

Comment: BufferedOutputStream is for writing not reading, so it does not have a readNextLine method.  Please post a relevant snippet of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the note. The problem that readNextLine, checks for \n. I use \r\n\r\n for knowing the end of my header. So while decoding the message and using readNextLine, it will removes my "tags".

Comment: You'll have reached the end of the header when the line you get back is "\r".

Comment: @ChrisNava so I don't need to look for \r\n\r\n using .index of ? I just need to look for \r ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read until `line.length() == 0.` That's the one between the two \r\n sequences. The line terminators are removed by `readLine(),` and it handles both \r\n, \n, and for that matter \r by itself as line terminators.

Comment: @Mahmoud I *did* show sample code. You shouldn't need anything more.

Answer (score -1):

You are using a LINE based parser so your string match can't extend to multiple lines.  In your wile loop, look for a single line containing just "\r" (or just "" if it strips \r also) and that will be the one blank line between the Header and the Content.

Comment: My head looks like:  Content-length 499 \r\n\r\n <?xml...etc

Comment: It does strip the line terminators.